# Raise Application Error in Trigger and still update table

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I'm facing some problem here, when the customer did not make payment in 60 days. The trigger will UPDATE the customer table and still RAISE the
error -20003.

What I've realize is that the update function will be canceled if the raise exception takes place.

Is there any way to go around doing this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cut_supply
BEFORE INSERT ON reading
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    cust_ID BILL.custID%TYPE;
    sent_date BILL.sentDate%TYPE;
    payment_date BILL.paymentdate%TYPE;
    bad_Status CUSTOMER.badStatus%TYPE;
    first_name CUSTOMER.firstName%TYPE;
    last_name CUSTOMER.lastName%TYPE;
    NRIC_No CUSTOMER.NRIC%TYPE;
  pRate_ID CUSTOMER.pRateID%TYPE;
  no_new_reading EXCEPTION;
CURSOR cust_cursor IS
        SELECT b.custID, b.sentDate, b.paymentDate, c.badStatus, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.NRIC, c.pRateID
        FROM bill b, customer c, reading r
        WHERE (sysdate - sentDate) > 20
        AND paymentDate is null
        AND b.custID = c.custID
        AND r.readingID = b.readingID
        FOR UPDATE OF c.badStatus;
BEGIN
   OPEN cust_cursor;  
   LOOP
        FETCH cust_cursor INTO cust_ID, sent_date, payment_date,
                             bad_Status, first_name, last_name, NRIC_No, pRate_ID;
        IF cust_cursor%NOTFOUND THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        IF cust_cursor%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'No customer found');
        ELSE
            UPDATE customer
            SET pRateID= 801, badStatus='Non Payment'
            WHERE CURRENT OF cust_cursor;
            RAISE no_new_reading;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cust_cursor;
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_new_reading THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20003,
        'Customer ' || first_name||''||last_Name ||
         ' water supply has been cut off' );
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```

Comment: Why are ypu raising an exception at all? What is supposed to happen, the session that is inserting the reading sees the `dbms_output` text (*if* thay are set up to see it, which you don't know), and they see the exception too, and... do what with that information? Why would you only check late-payment when a new reading happens anyway? Surely that sort of check should be a regular scheduled thing, maybe a daily sweep of all accounts or outstanding payments or something?

Comment: I agree with Alex here: your problems getting the technology working are symptomatic of the confusion in your design/architecture.  You need to address the workflows first: then you can code them properly.

Comment: @AlexPoole so would it be okay if i create a store procedure to update the customer table first then use a trigger to call my procedure to reject a the new reading?

Comment: Not if they're part of the same transaction, you have the same problem. (There is a way to do it but it is usually a bad idea). I don't understand the model really. Why would you reject the new reading? Why is there any connection between the two things?

Comment: RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR, in simple terms, will terminate the whole transaction (that invoked the trigger). You want the UPDATE, i.e. the TRANSACTION, to succeed, but also flag a particular account state. You have it seems set the account to this state, so what you need is another code post-transaction to check what the account state (in you UPDATE) was set and then display/alert an appropriate message to the end user.

Also in your code you check for %NOTFOUND and %ROWCOUNT = 0 - you might want to check if these check as you have them are not actually logically the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be solve in the following manner, create a procedure to update the customer table

```
create or replace procedure update_customer
as
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
update customer c set c.badStatus='Non Payment', c.pRateID=801 
where c.custID=
(
  select distinct c.custID
  FROM bill b, reading r
        WHERE (sysdate - sentDate) > 20
        AND paymentDate is null
        AND b.custID = c.custID
        AND r.readingID = b.readingID
);
commit;
end;
/
```

Use a trigger to call the procedure itself.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER cut_supply
BEFORE INSERT ON reading
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    cust_ID BILL.custID%TYPE;
    sent_date BILL.sentDate%TYPE;
    payment_date BILL.paymentdate%TYPE;
    bad_Status CUSTOMER.badStatus%TYPE;
    first_name CUSTOMER.firstName%TYPE;
    last_name CUSTOMER.lastName%TYPE;
    NRIC_No CUSTOMER.NRIC%TYPE;  
    reject_new_reading_excep EXCEPTION;
CURSOR cust_cursor IS 
     SELECT b.custID, b.sentDate, b.paymentDate, c.badStatus, c.firstName, c.lastName, c.NRIC
        FROM bill b, customer c, reading r
        WHERE (sysdate - sentDate) > 20
        AND paymentDate is null
        AND b.custID = c.custID
        AND r.readingID = b.readingID;
BEGIN
   OPEN cust_cursor;   
   LOOP
        FETCH cust_cursor INTO cust_ID, sent_date, payment_date, 
                             bad_Status, first_name, last_name, NRIC_No;

        IF cust_cursor%NOTFOUND THEN 
            EXIT;
        END IF;
        IF cust_cursor%ROWCOUNT = 0 THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'No customer found');
        ELSE
        update_customer;
        RAISE reject_new_reading_excep;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cust_cursor;
   COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN reject_new_reading_excep THEN
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR ( -20003, 
        'Customer ' || first_name||''||last_Name ||
        ' water supply has been cut off' );
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
/
```